# Ошибка при компиляции, при включенном ProGuard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-gradle

Дописав в `build.gradle` строчку `minifyEnabled true` , при сборке apk выкидывает ошибку:

> ```
> Error:Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Note: there were 377 duplicate class definitions.
>       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
> Warning: library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.utils.Utils
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.utils.Utils
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer$Result: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer$Result: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.utils.Utils
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial$Icon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial$Icon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.utils.Utils
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial$Icon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.accountswitcher.AccountHeader: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.BaseDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SwitchDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SwitchDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SwitchDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SwitchDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SwitchDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ToggleDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ToggleDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ToggleDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ToggleDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ToggleDrawerItem: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.Iconable: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.Iconable: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.Iconable: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.Iconable: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.IIcon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial$Icon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial$Icon
> Warning: com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.UIUtils: can't find referenced class com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial
> Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
> Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
> Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.BasicHttpCache: can't find referenced method 'void consumeQuietly(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)' in program class org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CacheKeyGenerator: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Consts
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CacheKeyGenerator: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Consts
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.RequestProtocolCompliance: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.RequestProtocolCompliance: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.RequestProtocolCompliance: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue
> Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.SHA256KeyHashingScheme: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String encodeHexString(byte[])' in library class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeListener
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyVetoException
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeListener
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeListener
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeListener
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class java.beans.VetoableChangeListener
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler$Prefix: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.AbstractBeanInvocationHandler$Prefix: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
> Warning: org.ini4j.spi.BeanTool: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
> Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
> Warning: there were 153 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
>          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
>          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
>          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
> Warning: there were 33 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
>          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
>          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
>          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
> Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
>          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>          You may need to recompile the code.
>          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
> Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
>          You probably need to update the library versions.
>          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> > Job failed, see logs for details
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 22s
> ```

Что нужно сделать для исправления и из за чего конфликт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О да. на ваше счастье сегодня я здесь (шучу). На самом деле proguard это очень страдальческая тема, но я попробую вам помочь:

Все предупреждения, что выведены по сути своей являются ошибками. Т.е. proguard случайно удаляет некоторые части программы, которых потом не хватает при компиляции. Например, у вас из явного это

```
com.mikepenz.materialdrawer
org.apache.http.impl.client.cache
org.ini4j.spi
```

После определения потерянных частей, вы начинаете дописывать правила в proguard-файл, позволяющие сказать proguard что это удалять не нужно. К сожалению, знать что дописать - это большая проблема. Я поискал правила для первой либы, и гугл сказал мне, что proguard-а для него нет)) Упс, сказал я. Как же так, если не работает. Но гугл сказал, сам виноват... Предлагаю вам второй вариант. Сначала вы добавляете весь проект в profuard:

```
-dontwarn com.**
```

Пробуете скомпилироваться. Если получилось - отлично. Если нет, но хотя бы часть ошибок пропало - пытаетесь нагуглить дополнительные строки, чтобы компиляция заработала. После первой успешной компиляции вы постепенно сужаете область выделения (т.е. не включаете весь проект в доверенную зону, а пытаетесь нащупать именно те, что теряются):

```
-dontwarn com.my.project.adapters.**
```

И так снова до тех пор, пока не заработает. Вычищаете лишнее. После того, как вы примерно обозначили все - вы начинаете тестировать приложение. Скорее всего в одном или нескольких местах оно упадет (да, отсутствие ошибок при компиляции с включенным proguard, это еще не показатель, что их нет). После того, как версия протестирована и вычищена - вы радуетесь. Полностью проделать этот цикл лично для меня очень тяжело, но других решений нет. Обычно на это уходит дня три...

P?S? Если вдруг кто знает, пожалуйста напишите, вы облегчите нам жизнь.

Comment: ну конечно, вы можете послать прогуард в ж... и залить проект так.

Comment: просто "посмотрел" другие приложения, как они выглядят,  и оказалось, что они очень хорошо "запутаны" внутри. Посмотрев своё приложение, всё вылезло настолько чисто и аккуратно, что мне кажется взяв и скопировав весь код себе в проект, можно сделать отличную копию приложения.. Хотелось бы всё это дело шифровать...

Comment: хорошее желание. бейтесь с прогуардом - первый раз это сложно

Comment: Подскажите полный путь к файлу proguard-rules.pro , ну или путь, где его надо создать ..

Comment: рядом с gradle в папке app

Comment: большое спасибо!